# WPF variable custom button shape

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to desinge a Template for a Button, which addapts the shape of the Button. I want to give the shape as Attribute to the control. Like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
   <Button.Shape>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="MyImage"/>
   </Button.Shape>
</Button>
```

I tried to use the `OpacityMask`-Attribute of the Button, but somehow I coulden't specify in the template on which element I want to apply the mask.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Test" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" OpacityMask"{TemplateBinding OpacityMask}">
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaff00ff"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I already tried something like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
   <Button.OpacityMask>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="MyImage"/>
   </Button.OpacityMask>
</Button>
```

But then i can't change the background anymore. I know, I could put every button in a Grid with the background I want, but I try to learn the concept of Templates and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. :)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to cut out a Button's Background in a certain shape (outline)?

Comment: I want a button with a custom shape. But I want to specify the trigger-area of the Click-Event independently from the visual shape.